# How to determine the position vector p for a vector equation r=p+td.

Tags: vectors

With a vector equation *r*=*p*+t*d* can you use any point the  vector passes through as position vector p?

For instance if one has line 4y + 3x = 0 (and needs to make a vector equation for it) then *d*, the direction vector, is calculated from the gradient:

m = -3/4

direction vector = 4 *i* - 3 *j*.

But what is *p*? I could put infinite numbers into 4y + 3x = 0, for instance when y=3 then x=-4, the position vector for this is -4 *i* + 3 *j* but is that vector *p*?

How do I decide what number to put into the function to find *p*?

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, there are infinitely many choices for $p$, as it must any point on the line, i.e. in your case any solution of the equation
$$4y+3x=0.$$
An easy choice could be $p=(0,0)$.

Remark: note that also $d$ is **not unique** as any vector which is a (non-zero) multiple of $d$ does the same job. For example $d=(-8,6)$.